# Picking video file on Android 10: Error NdkMediaExtractor can't create HTTP service

Tags: android, unity-game-engine, video

I'm using **Unity version 2019.4.3f1** I'm trying to load local video file on *Android 10* device (*Samsung A90*) from the gallery but I'm not able getting this error:

```
2020/07/10 20:24:51.603 8430 8620 Error NdkMediaExtractor can't create http service
2020/07/10 20:24:51.603 8430 8620 Warn Unity AndroidVideoMedia: Error opening extractor: -10002
2020/07/10 20:24:51.603 8430 8620 Warn Unity (Filename:  Line: 469)
2020/07/10 20:24:51.603 8430 8620 Warn Unity
```

Any suggestions on how to fix this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to fix this issue, in my case, the problem was "URL" for the final path I used:

```
VideoPlayer.url = "file://" + _url;
```

-I removed "file://" from the final path string and now all works perfectly.

Hope this will help somebody!